# Jquery / JS Order Form - does not update when last item is added or removed

Tags: jquery

Below is a script I have pieced together. I'm having a problem with total and sum calculations updating when I add or remove an item to the Order. This seems to partially work if you use the code below and add more than one item, however, in jsfiddle it does not work at all... see http://jsfiddle.net/w6kryfLd/

Any Tips are appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    .price {width:60px; text-align:right;}
    .qty {width:40px; text-align:right;}
    .amount {width:80px; text-align:right;}
    a {cursor:pointer; color:#001eff;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>PRODUCTS</h2>
<p>Instructions: Click on Products below to add to Your Order.</p>
<div class="btnSave" id="item1" onClick="setFld(this.id);upAmt();" style="cursor:pointer">
Product 1... $<span class="price">5.00</span></div>
<div class="btnSave" id="item2" onClick="setFld(this.id);upAmt();" style="cursor:pointer">
Product 2... $<span class="price">10.00</span></div>
<div class="btnSave" id="item3" onClick="setFld(this.id);upAmt();" style="cursor:pointer">
Product 3... $<span class="price">2.95</span></div>
----------------------------------

<div class="searchbox">
<input type="hidden" id="itmName" />
</div>

<div id="order">
<h2>YOUR ORDER</h2>
$<input type="text" id="total" class="total" value="">

</div>
</div>

----------------------------------------------<br>
<a href="#" onclick="upAmt()">update</a>

<script>
//Add new item button
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.btnSave').click(function() {
            addItem($('#itmName').val());
        });
    });


//Add item to the list
    function addItem(name) {
    var container = $('#order');

    var html = '<li>'+name+' Qty. <input class="qty" type="text" name="qty" onChange="upAmt()" value="1"> $<span class="amount">0</span> <a>remove</a></li>';
    container.append($(html));
    }

//remove li box from order
    $(function(){
      $(document).on('click','#order a',function(){
        $(this).parent('li').remove();
        return false;
      });
    });

//Copies clicked item to input which is passed to order form
function setFld(clicked_id){
    document.getElementById('itmName').value = document.getElementById(clicked_id).innerHTML;
}

//Calculates item totals and order sum
$(document).ready(function(){

    upAmt();
    $('.qty').change(function() {
        upAmt();
    });
});


function upAmt()
{
    var sum = 0.00;
    $('#order > li').each(function() {
        var qty = $(this).find('.qty').val();
        var price = $(this).find('.price').html();
        var amount = (qty*price)
        sum+=amount;
        $(this).find('.amount').html(''+amount);
    });
    //just update the total to sum  
    $('.total').val(sum);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest abandoning your strategy of "using the DOM with events to update other parts of the DOM". You should be using JavaScript to represent the products, cart and cart items as objects and then updating the DOM when changes happen to those Objects.

I wrote this quick example of what I am talking about:

http://codepen.io/dustinpoissant/pen/ramNdN

```
function formatNumber(n, format){
  if(!format||format.length==0)return n+"";
  var w = Math.floor(n);
  var d = n-w;
  var b = format.indexOf(".");
  var a = ((format.length-b)-1);
  w=w+"";
  while(w.length<b)w="0"+w;
  d=Math.round( d*Math.pow(10,a) )+"";
  while(d.length<a)d+="0";
  return w+"."+d;
};
var Store = {
  products: [],
  addProduct: function(upc, name, price){
    Store.products.push({
      upc: upc,
      name: name,
      price: price
    });
  },
  getProduct: function(upc){
    for(var i=0;i<Store.products.length;i++)
      if(Store.products[i].upc == upc) return Store.products[i];
    return false;
  },
  displayProducts: function(){
    var html = "";
    for(var i=0;i<Store.products.length;i++)
      html += "<button type='button' class='product' onClick='Store.cart.addItem("+Store.products[i].upc+");'>"+Store.products[i].name+": $"+formatNumber(Store.products[i].price, "#.##")+"</button>";
    document.getElementById("products").innerHTML = html;
  },
  cart: {
    items: [],
    addItem: function(upc, qty){
      /* qty's default value is 1 */
      if(qty===undefined)qty=1;
      if( Store.cart.updateItem(upc, qty, true) === false){
        Store.cart.items.push( {
          upc: upc,
          qty: qty
        } );
      }
      Store.cart.toHTML();
    },
    updateItem: function(upc, qty, append){
      var updated = false;
      for(var i=0;i<Store.cart.items.length;i++){
        if(Store.cart.items[i].upc == upc){
          updated = true;
          if(append)
            Store.cart.items[i].qty += qty;
          else{
            Store.cart.items[i].qty = qty;
            Store.cart.toHTML();
          }
        }
      }
      return updated;
    },
    removeItem: function(upc){
      for(var i=0;i<Store.cart.items.length;i++)
        if(Store.cart.items[i].upc == upc) Store.cart.items.splice(i, 1);
      Store.cart.toHTML();
    },
    toHTML: function(){
      var html = "";
      for(var i=0;i<Store.cart.items.length;i++){
        var product = Store.getProduct(Store.cart.items[i].upc);
        html += "<div class='item'><input type='number' class='item-qty' value='"+Store.cart.items[i].qty+"' onChange='Store.cart.updateItem("+product.upc+",this.value);' /> "+product.name+" @ $"+formatNumber(product.price, "#.##")+" each = $"+formatNumber(Store.cart.items[i].qty*product.price,"#.##")+" (<a href='#' class='item-removeBtn' onclick='Store.cart.removeItem("+product.upc+");return false;'>remove</a>)</div>";
      }
      document.getElementById("cart-items").innerHTML = html;
      document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = formatNumber(Store.cart.getTotal(), "#.##");
    },
    getTotal: function(){
      var total = 0;
      for(var i=0;i<Store.cart.items.length;i++){
        var item = Store.cart.items[i];
        var price = 0;
        for(var p=0;p<Store.products.length;p++)
          if(Store.products[p].upc == item.upc)
            total += item.qty*Store.products[p].price;
      }
      return total;
    }
  }
};
Store.addProduct(1, "Teddy Bear", 12.99);
Store.addProduct(2, "Deck of Cards", 4.68);
Store.addProduct(3, "Bar of Soap", 2.95);
Store.addProduct(4, "Magazine", 4.99);
Store.addProduct(5, "Pack of Gum", 2.67);
```

I suppose it would be possible doing it the way you are attempting but I'd highly advise against it. If you want I will fix your errors and get your code working but it's the wrong approach.

Comment: I just noticed that I currently I allow you to buy a negative number of a product. Opps. but still you get the idea.

Comment: Dustin,Wow! I did not expect to get a complete rewrite.  You are amazing! I will spend some time with your code and give you attribution. I will also keep you in mind for paid projects. This is my first-time submitting a question to stackoverflow. What is the best way to contact you?

Comment: After spending some time on your code, while it works great, it will not work for my needs. I need to  extract product data from html on a separate page verses from the the script. Here is why... I will be using another script that searches for product data as you type (see http://listjs.com). I had planned on separating this data from the page that contains the cart script using an iframe. By doing this I can create separate pages for each product category which can include hundreds of products.

Comment: Each category page would be loaded in the iframe via a link on the parent page. Products listed on these category pages (when selected, Clicked) would be passed to the shopping cart on the parent page.